# React Js Inline style not working on loop condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am getting problem when doing loop in react JS. I want to make a different background for each item according to the data I have created. I tried to use the inline style to make it dynamic, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions or solutions regarding this?

```
        {
            main.map((item, index) => (
                <a key={index} href='#' className="col-12 main-item-img" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${item.bg})`, backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundSize: 'cover'}}>
                    <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                    <img src={item.logo} className='item-img' alt={item.region} srcSet="" />
                    <p>{item.desc}</p>
                    <div className="overlay"></div>
                </a>
            ))
        }
```

Comment: Have you verified that `item.bg` is a valid file path/url?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni Yup, it's a valid url. i also tried using external url like `style={{background: 'url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1641221179154-08bbe987a8be?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8=w=8=autop=w =8=autopDB8&fGVufDB8=w= 80)'}}` but didn't change anything. But when I try without loop, it works properly

Comment: change the <a> to <div> and try again

Comment: @DininduKanchana still not working :((

Comment: Solved! The problem is not in the loop but in the slick slider that I use. In the description I didn't explain that I was using the slick slider because I thought the problem was in the loop.

i just need to add <div> before <a>

Comment: Thankyou all for trying to help me 

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!** The problem is not in the loop but in the slick slider that I use. In the description I didn't explain that I was using the slick slider because I thought the problem was in the loop.

i just need to add  before . The result is like this

```
    <Slider {...carouselSettings} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        {
            main.map((item, index) => (
                <div> //add this element
                    <a key={index} href='#' className="col-12 main-item-img" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${item.bg})`, backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundSize: 'cover'}}>
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <img src={item.logo} className='item-img' alt={item.region} srcSet="" />
                        <p>{item.desc}</p>
                        <div className="overlay"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            ))
        }
    </Slider>
```